Sonarqube-10.6.0.92116 Java 17 Error custom plugin
*which versions are you using: sonarqube-10.6.0.92116
*how is SonarQube deployed: zip
*what are you trying to achieve:
*I have a java sonar custom plugin project compiled in Java8 which I am trying to deploy in sonarqube-10.6.0.92116 but I see the following error
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet
Tried to compile the project in Java 17 and deploy but see the same error.
